Accessing my bitcoin
When I first invested $10;into Bitcoin it hadn't taken off yet,I forgot about it and then recently started receiving emails saying I needed to do something with my Bitcoin money but I have no idea what to do. I need help to get my Bitcoin into my wallet so I can receive the money that's been there for awhile.

Does this answer your question? Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?. Those emails are almost certainly fake, sent by conman who will trick you into sending fake release fees.
